# How do I decide where to write text on the console? (ie: 97% 98% 99%....)

Tags: c++, console, output, screen, coordinates

I'd like to be able to tell `cout` where to write some specific text so that, for instance, I can show an increasing percentage that will be "updated" by overwriting it every time it changes.
Something like a `Progress: 97%` that becomes `Progress: 98%` and then `Progress: 99%` all in the same place, possibly without re-processing the whole screen output every time.

I remember QBasic (from the very old days) having a method specific for this purpose, but it seems I cant find anything more "modern" in C++.
Wherever I go, I see people mentioning `Curses` or other "cursed" libraries that, I'm afraid, would bloat my code with unwanted features and possible holes and malfunctions.
Or worse, they suggest to just flood the output stream with tens or hundreds of `\n` to "hide the dust under the carpet".

Another idea that has just come to my mind would be to build some kind of array that stores outputs to be then processed in a looped `cout`-ish function so that all I have to do is to change the part of the array that I need to, somehow purge the current screen content and re-output it all over again with the modifications.
Except this would still require Windows' cursed `system` library to clear the screen or just `Curses`; or a `\n` machine-gun function to hide the former output.

Any more elegant and/or C++ standard based viable solution?

Comment: _"C++ standard based viable solution"_ No, since the C++ standard doesn't have any notion of your console terminal capabilities.

Comment: @Melkon That is exactly one of the forum threads I've already gone through and, read my question more carefully, an almost complete collection of what I just dont want to do in my code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then any other something-else-based-but-still-elegant-and-viable solution that wont bring trash into my code? (Edited my question according to your clarification).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any more elegant and C++ standard based viable solution?

Basically no, because as mentioned C++ standard has no notion of your terminals capabilities.

There's the [standard escape character literal `'\b'`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for putting a backspace (position the cursor back within the current line) though. This should work with most available terminal types.

Comment: Gonna "kiss and tell".

Comment: It works pretty well, although it's right and proper to specify that `\b` doesnt work just as the `Backspace` key; it only moves the console cursor back, where one can then start `cout`-ing new output that will overwrite the former one. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind, if the output is redirected to a file, it will become completely unreadable.

Comment: @SergeyA It's just for things like menus and percentage progressions, I'm not gonna use this escape sequence to modify text in files. For that it's way easier/safer to use `fstream` class' methods. Thanks to both of you!!

Comment: @ZehryoKarham, you did not get the point. I did not mean to modify the file. What I meant is the case when your program is run like that: `./app > out`

Comment: @SergeyA I'm afraid I have no idea what that `./app > out` string means. This is just for console interface purposes, nothing that includes a `\b` or `\r` escape sequence is ever going to be redirected to a file.

Comment: @ZehryoKarham, than you need not worry about my words :)

Answer (score 3):

For the simple code as shown most people would use a simple console output followed by \r. This will move cursor to the left position on the same line on most terminals, so you can print 'on top' of already printed line. This is definitely not C++ standard, but I find it elegant enough.

Comment: One needs to make sure that already outputted stuff is overwritten (spaced out) correctly. Though it's shorter by means of characters written.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, the benfit is, though, that if the output is redirected to the file, it will be readable (just 100 lines repeated over). The output with backspace will be unreadable.

Comment: πάνταῥεῖ already gave me what I best needed, but your answer is still a very interesting variation that would come in handy in some situations. Thanks to you too.